# Why didn't Four warn the rest of Dauntless what was going to happen?

Tags: plot-explanation, divergent

In [*Divergent* (2014)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1840309/), Max and Jeanine Mathews are planning an attack on Abnegation because they apparently hold secrets and are destroying the city slowly.

When Four discovered (while working in the control room) that there was something a bit suspicious going on, he went to investigate and uncovered information based on an attack simulation: when it would happen, how it would happen, who is involved in the plot, and who it was against.

He finds out that Erudite is trying to get hold of information that only Marcus (former leader of the city and from Abnegation) knows, so they can develop a serum that puts everyone in Dauntless but the Divergent (the Erudite said the Divergent must be killed on discovery as they were a threat) under a simulation so that they are tricked into attacking Abnegation.

**When Four figured this out, why didn't he go and warn the rest of Dauntless so then the Erudite couldn't succeed in tricking Dauntless to get the *Simulation Serum*?**

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Four doesn't actually know what they wanted to do with the serum. He probably had an idea but didn't want to tell anyone because it could have impacted his job and, of course, could have been completely wrong. He also obviously didn't trust anyone in dauntless as, it wasn't until he met Tris, that he confided in someone about it. In the end, if Four told anyone, it could have meant that people got killed for being curious. Everyone knows that Four hates people getting killed or more, him killing people.

Hope this helped